# Graying whole page to focus on DIV

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a JSP, that includes 3 more JSPs. On click of a button on one of these included JSPs, I need to gray the whole window content. How this can be done? I was trying to append a child(image) to the parent window but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `<div class="glasspane">` to the `<body>` element, having the following style:

```
.glasspane {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

Of course, this `<div>` element should be removed when appropriate.

Comment: How could I add it? And body element of which JSP?

Comment: I don't know how your final DOM is structured, and I presume you have no iframes into which these JSPs are loaded, and the whole DOM represents just a single document. If so, just use the `document.body` element.

Comment: Guess you need a good JavaScript reference. `var paneElement = document.createElement("div"); paneElement.className = "glasspane"; document.body.appendChild(paneElement);`

Comment: I added the image. It got appended at the bottom of the page. Is this due to {positon}?

Comment: Yes, the full CSS rule should be specified as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some jQuery I've used for a similar purpose:

```
$('body')
.prepend('<div class="veil">&nbsp;</div>')
.children('.veil')
.css({ position:'fixed' ,top:'0' ,left:'0' ,width:'100%' ,height:'100%' 
,opacity:'0.5' ,backgroundColor:'gray' ,zIndex:7                })
;
```